# How to enable a Nested Recyclerview scroll when it has the same scrolling orientation as the parent RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to a RecyclerView (**nested**) inside the ViewHolder of another RecyclerView (**parent**). Both **nested** and **parent** have fixed heights. The **nested** is placed in the bottom of the **parent**.

If I use the **parent** with a LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL and the **nested** with a LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL everything works as expected, but if both RecyclerViews have the same orientation the **nested** can't hear the *move* event -- thus not being able to scroll.

What should I do in this case? How can I have both RecyclerViews scrolling Horizontally and be able to scroll the **nested** separately from the **parent**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my case I have the **nested** in the bottom of the **parent** I used a custom RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener and a custom LinearLayoutManager, both of them added to the **parent**.

In the LinearLayoutManager I created a method for enabling and disabling the scroll.

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally();
}

public void setScrollEnabled(boolean isScrollEnabled) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled;
}
```

On the custom RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener I started checking the area the user touched and disabled/enabled the **parent's** scrolling capability.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getY() > (viewHolderHeight - nestedRecyclerViewHeight)) {
        mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

What this is doing is: whenever the user touches an Item of the **parent** the system calls onInterceptTouchEvent and if the user touches the area where the **nested** should be it disables the scroll of the **parent**. And it enables it back if the touch happens outside of the **nested** area.

I searched a lot to reach this answer and actually mixed a few answers that used the Custom LinearLayoutManager for disabling the scroll of a recyclerview, and the RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener for disabling any interaction on the RecyclerView.

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar problem.